# Close votes review list duplicate link

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

In the Close Votes list, when the voting reason is possible duplicate, what is the way to find the link for the reason of the closed vote?  Sometimes the person who requested a close for this reason puts the link in the comments, and sometimes not. So it seems as if the only way to find the link is to go into the close reason screen, select possible duplicate, and see the link they selected there.  Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an easier way:

> [image]

That tab will show you the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: How did I not see that before???  Thank you very much.